# Package org.junit does not exist Java Netbeans

Tags: java, junit

I've somehow broken my Junit (Pulling a project from git) after installing it with netbeans.
As you can see I'm missing some libraries. 
Any help on fixing this would be greatly appreciated. [Missing Libraries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T2uhf.png)

Comment: The image is not helpful. Could you please provide git link for the project or what kind of project it is (i.e., maven/gradle). If it is simple plain java project then you need to to download junit jar from maven repo and add it to the classpath. otherwise add junit in the dependencies of `build.gradle` if it is gradle project or `pom.xml` if it is maven project.

Comment: Unfortunately i do not know how to see if my project (Java FX) is maven or gradle, Since posting this i created a new JavaFX Project in netbeans then when i added a junit test i was prompted to use the netbeans plugin portal to install junit However it was unable to connect (i tried turning off firewall).

Comment: okay. maven project means it would have `pom.xml` in root folder and gradle means `build.gradle` in root folder. Also, as I mentioned could you please provide git link for the project?

Comment: Unfortunately i cannot as it is a private project that i cannot give access to, is there anything else i can do, I have searched my project directory and cannot find pom.xml, i only found build.impl Build.xml

Comment: okay. looks like your project is java project with ant build. so I suggest you to google online how to add junit dependency for ant for test scope.